# Verb for watching over the city

Tags: single-word-requests

What is the word which is used as a verb which describes the action where a superhero, such as Batman, stands on the top of a building and watches over the city, so that he can find out where crimes are taking place?

Comment: Welcome to English Language & Usage. You might try "survey"..

Answer (score 2):

Batman *surveils* the city;
 *surveil* is the verb form of *surveillance*:

> close watch kept over someone or something (as by a detective)

<sub>(source: [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/surveillance))</sub>